# Spring / roo and three tier architecture with firewall and dmz

Tags: spring, firewall, spring-roo, dmz

we have a big three tier ejb application, which consists of a webserver (apache tomcat) located in a dmz(demilitarized zone), an application server(jboss) and a database server.

Our client requires that there is no connection between the dmz and the database server.

Now we are thinking about integration of Spring(ROO).

The default deployment model for roo is a web application (war) which connects to a database server.

In our scenario the web application would be running in the dmz, but connections to the database would violate our clients security requirements.

what is the best way to solve this problem (assuming the security requirements can't be changed)?

all the best,

Comment: How were you planning to do it w/o Spring Roo?

Comment: Where is the JBoss instance located? Are you allowed to connect to that?

Answer (score 1):

put the war in the jboss application-server and let an apache-server (or something like that) on the dmz forward the requests to it.

in general i would really think again about using roo. it does not yet support multi-module projects. so the integration between the new roo-app and the server-code deployed on your application server is complicated.

we did the this sort of thing at my work and the problems that arise from it weigh out the benefits of roo's scaffolding.

Comment: I run into the same problem for my project.  I have raised a [Spring Roo JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3296) - please vote if you think it will be useful :)